# Slick Slider setPosition for navigation

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup, slick.js

I am using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) within [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html).

The slider can contain a couple of items, and has it's own thumbnail nav.

Because the popup sets the slider to display:none I've use:

```
$('.slider-products').slick('setPosition');
```

within a callback function when the popup opens and changes.

I've created a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybzeQE?editors=1010).

You'll see a couple of issues, firstly the thumbnail navigation doesn't load in correctly due to the setPosition not being set, but I've been unable to get this to work. If you resize the window you'll see it.

Secondly on the second (purple) and third (green) items do not start on their first items. Each slider gets it's own unique class, so they shouldn't be interfering with each other.

Comment: How should it behave? What is it that you're looking to fix?

Comment: sorry i also worked with both libraries but i do not get what you want. can you show us mockups or explain how it should work?

Comment: One issue I can see in the pen... The callbacks you assign in your magnific-popup routinely manipulate `$('.slider-products')`. That means all three sliders, not just the once currently in the popup.